# ¿Como almacenar parte de una url y al hacer click se sume al resto del enlace y abra la pagina?

Tags: javascript

Soy nuevo en js y espero solucion.

tengo varias url y todas comienzan por **https: // 2.bp.blogspot.com**, ahora quiero almacenar esta como una primera parte y el resto en los enlaces algo como esto:

```
Javascript=<br>
var **base**= "https: // 2.bp.blogspot.com" (algo como esto no se como se hace)
<br><br>
HTML=<br>
< a href="/-aVpKfrY4hCE/WUBqnQNNt-I/AAAAAAADLKU/iIMtGqmPe7o4EMo2ZlqEr0QR3qCC_-4MwCKgBGAs/s3200/SecW4rs_05_0157.webp">Imagen 01< /a><br>
< a href="/-3FIhHPOdz_w/WUBqnc-30NI/AAAAAAADLKU/8G-BHCDwyi4DHyhORNwLfXudSIVnKO2ugCKgBGAs/s3200/SecW4rs_05_0162.webp">Imagen 02< /a><br><br>
RESULTADO al hacer click=<br>
< a href="**base +**/-aVpKfrY4hCE/WUBqnQNNt-I/AAAAAAADLKU/iIMtGqmPe7o4EMo2ZlqEr0QR3qCC_-4MwCKgBGAs/s3200/SecW4rs_05_0157.webp">Imagen 01< /a><br>
< a href="**base +**/-3FIhHPOdz_w/WUBqnc-30NI/AAAAAAADLKU/8G-BHCDwyi4DHyhORNwLfXudSIVnKO2ugCKgBGAs/s3200/SecW4rs_05_0162.webp">Imagen 02< /a>
<br><br>
```

Es decir, al hacer click abrir la url a pesar de que son distentas pero con la misma primera parte almacenada.

Comment: Genera la url antes y luego la pones en el href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un href abre un enlace directamente.

Puedes crear una función en javascript y hacer que reciba la segunda parte desde el HTML mediante `onclick()`

```js
var base = "https://2.bp.blogspot.com";

function MiFuncion($segundaParte){      
        //Concatenar la primera parte "base" con la segunda parte $segundaParte
        var enlaceEntero = base.concat($segundaParte);
        //Abrir URL
        window.open(enlaceEntero,"_self")
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="MiFuncion('/segundaParteDelEnlace.com')">Haz click aquí para abrir el enlace</button>
<br>
<a onclick="MiFuncion('/segundaParteDelEnlace.com')">Haz click aquí para abrir el enlace</a>
```

Comment: Cierto. Y si necesitas la misma *URL* de base para varias funciones diferentes, puedes guardarla en una variable global, un elemento HTML oculto, etc...

Comment: Exacto @Orici, para cambios de dominio por ejemplo.

Comment: gracias me a funcionado, pero ahora como hago eso de las funciones global, y lo del elemento html oculto.

Comment: Variable global, la declaras fuera de la función y así estaría accesible a las funciones que declares. Práctica poco recomendada (fugas de memoria) pero a veces es necesaria y si no abusas no sería un problema... En cuanto al elemento oculto, lo normal es poner un *input* de tipo *hidden* y le asignas la URL como valor, solo que tendrás que recuperarlo en cada función en que quieras usarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Sin usar javascript, y asumiendo que todos los enlaces de tu página fuesen a ese sitio, puedes añadir en el `<head>` de tu página lo siguiente:

`<base href="https://2.bp.blogspot.com">`

y todos los enlaces relativos usarán esa dirección como base

Comment: ok, ustedes han abierto un mundo de posibilidades jejejejeee gracias, pero ahora no puedo detenerme y pido disculpas por saber mas y mas. Ahora, como haria para cargar un iframe pero utilizando un tag o algo asi, para que se cargue automaticamente del mismo modo, guardando una parte de la url.

Comment: Este *tag HTML* es muy interesante, sobretodo a la hora de cargar imágenes y otros recursos, y puede muy bien sustituir al *input hidden* que mencione antes. Más sobre su uso en: https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_base.asp

Comment: la respuesta me a funcionado, pero falta algo, por ejemplo que se ejecute desde algo como esto: $(function() { $("a").on("click", function() { })}) y que el valor para agregar sea obtenido desde $(this).attr("href"), para que sea mas universal al ser implementado